# Отслеживание нажатий на клавиши с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура

Я пишу программу, которая должна отслеживать нажатие на клавиши.
Вот код:

```
import keyboard

translate = {
    'up':' нажал на клавишу ',
    'down':' отпустил клавишу '
}


def print_pressed_keys(e):
    print(
        'Пользователь {}{}'.format(translate[e.event_type], e.name)
        )


keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

Но когда я нажимаю на клавишу, программа пишет, что я ее отпускаю,
а когда отпускаю - пишет что наживаю на кнопку.
Что не так с кодом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `translate` ошибка - перепутаны местами `up` и `down`.

Для `up` (`event_type` когда клавиша отпущена) у вас сообщение `нажал на клавишу`, а для `down` - наоборот.

Поменяйте местами:

```
translate = {
    'down':' нажал на клавишу ',
    'up':' отпустил клавишу '
}
```

Comment: Точно.     
Как я мог так ошибиться?)    
Спасибо за помощь.